# Count new lines in file last 1 minute

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

With bash, how to count new lines appended to file the last 1 minute?

What would be smartest if you want to count new lines for the last 1 minute in multiple files simultanously and get output?

I have tried a few things, but i can not find a good solution.

I might try to use a programming language instead of Bash

Comment: You can check if file was modified last minute, but there is no way to check which lines were appended in last minute - you would need to make a backup first (every minute?) and then compare modified file with backup to get appended lines.

Comment: + Or store somewhere (same every 1 minute) the lines quantity and than calculate a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `wc -l` twice and subtract the results.

```
before=$(wc -l < yourfile)
sleep 60
after=$(wc -l < yourfile)
let dif=after-before
echo "$dif"
```

You may also just print the last `$dif` lines:

```
tail -n$dif yourfile
```

Although more lines could have been appended in the mean time, none of the operations are atomic here.

If you want to track incremental changes (at least the number of added lines), just log the output of `wc -l` every minute. However, there is no way to do this without knowing in advance that you will need this. Unless you have timestamps on every line, you can't know what part of the file was added when.

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  tail -c 1 > /dev/null
  sleep 60
  wc -l
} < your-file
```

With `ksh93`:

```
{ sleep 60; wc -l; } < your-file <#((EOF))
```

That opens the file, seeks to the end (in the first one reading and discarding one byte), then sleeps for 60 seconds, and then calls `wc -l` to count the number of newline characters in between the position we were at 1 minute ago and the (new) end of the file (if it's greater).

Note that it only reads the section that was added within those 60 seconds. If the file has been rewritten fully, that won't take into account an eventual change in the number of newline characters in the original part of the file.

Also, it checks changes to the original file even if that file has been deleted and/or a file by the same name has been recreated or linked to the directory the file was opened from originally.

If you want to know at which rate lines are being added to a log file, another option is to use `pv -l` with `tail -f`:

```
for f in *access_log; do
  tail -fn0 -- "$f" | pv -cN "$f" -ral > /dev/null &
done
wait
```

`-ra` for current and average rate. `-l` so the rate is expressed in number of *lines* per second.

Answer (score 2):

This is my final solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *access_log; do
        (
        before=$(wc -l < $i)
        sleep 10
        after=$(wc -l < $i)
        let dif=after-before
        echo "$i: $dif"
        ) &
done
```